# C has triggered a breakpoint by second dynamic allocation

Tags: c, malloc

first, I'm sorry I'm not good at English. I'm korean student, i used a translator.

I want to make code to operate on large numbers in C.

There is a code:

```
#define <stdio.h>
#define <stdlib.h>
#define <string.h>

typedef struct _Node{

    struct _Node* head;
    struct _Node* tail;
    char ch;

} Node;

/* This part is the part where Node* is allocated, and the value is received and stored. (Is this correct grammar? I don't know.) */

int getLargeInt(Node** head) {
    Node* temp = NULL;
    char ch;
    int len = 0;

    while (1) {
        ch = getc(stdin);

        if (ch == '\n') break;
        if (*head == NULL) {

            *head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            (*head)->head = NULL;
            (*head)->tail = NULL;

            (*head)->ch = &ch;
            len++;

        } else {

            temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

            (*head)->tail = temp;
            temp->head = *head;
            *head = temp;
            (*head)->tail = NULL;

            (*head)->ch = &ch;
            len++;
        }
    }
    return len;
}

/* This part is a function that adds two input strings (integers). */

void addLarge(Node* n1, Node* n2, int n1_len, int n2_len) {
    int i = 0;
    int res = 0;
    char* ch = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * ((n1_len > n2_len) ? n1_len + 1 : n2_len + 1));

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++) {
        if (i < n1_len)
            res += n1->ch - '0';
        if (i < n2_len)
            res += n2->ch - '0';
        if (n1 != NULL)
            n1 = n1->head;
        if (n2 != NULL)
            n2 = n2->head;

        ch[i] = res % 10 + '0';
        res /= 10;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++) {
        printf("%d", ch[strlen(ch) - i - 1] - '0');
    }
    free(ch);

}

int main() {

    Node* temp = NULL;
    Node* num1 = NULL;
    Node* num2 = NULL;
    int i, j, len = 0;
    int n1_len = 0, n2_len = 0;
    char ch;
    char* res;

    printf("first integer >> ");
    n1_len = getLargeInt(&num1);

    printf("second integer >> ");
    n2_len = getLargeInt(&num2);

    printf("select arithmetic symbol >> ");
    ch = getc(stdin);

    switch (ch) {
    case '+':
        //addLarge(num1, num2, n1_len, n2_len);
        break;
    }



    while (num1 != NULL) {
        if (num1->tail != NULL)
            while (num1->tail != NULL)
                num1 = num1->tail;

        temp = num1;
        num1 = num1->head;
        free(temp);
    }

    while (num2 != NULL) {
        if (num2->tail != NULL)
            while (num2->tail != NULL)
                num2 = num2->tail;

        temp = num2;
        num2 = num2->head;
        free(temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

problem is here:

```
            temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); // or any second malloc
```

The problem arises from the second dynamic allocation.

please help me...

+)

After updating visual studio 2019 it worked fine; But after the triggered breakpotin error in the free(ch) part, the same problem occurred.
That's why I added the addition function.
Thanks comment.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. We cannot compile and run the code snippet, and we don't know what input you use, what output or behavior you expect and what exactly happens instead. Your code looks like a linked list. Explain how the list grows and how the nodes should be linked with a few steps of example input. *You cannot use `strcpy` for single characters.* Use `(*head)->ch = ch;`.

Comment: BTW: The return type of `getc` is `int`, not `char`. This is necessary to distinguish `EOF` from valid characters.

Comment: Edited. Would this be ok?

Comment: Please make sure to run exactly the code in the question. Copy&paste the code to the question instead of re-typing. `#define <stdio.h>` does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Without a description how the code is supposed to work, especially details about the linked list, it is difficult to suggest a solution.

Currently I can only point out the details of the problem.

After fixing the obvious errors, I compiled the program with `gcc` using options `-g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined`

When runnig the code I get

```
==233==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000228 at pc 0x560460231420 bp 0x7ffe813e7260 sp 0x7ffe813e7250
READ of size 8 at 0x603000000228 thread T0
    #0 0x56046023141f in main /home/main.c:107
    #1 0x7fafdd6e6082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
    #2 0x56046023030d in _start (/home/a.out+0x330d)

0x603000000228 is located 8 bytes inside of 24-byte region [0x603000000220,0x603000000238)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fafdec2340f in __interceptor_free ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:122
    #1 0x5604602314b4 in main /home/main.c:112
    #2 0x7fafdd6e6082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fafdec23808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x56046023079d in getLargeInt /home/main.c:37
    #2 0x5604602311ee in main /home/main.c:89
    #3 0x7fafdd6e6082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /home/main.c:107 in main
```

```
    while (num1 != NULL) {
        if (num1->tail != NULL)
            while (num1->tail != NULL) /* line 107 */
                num1 = num1->tail;

        temp = num1;
        num1 = num1->head; /* line 112 */
        free(temp);
    }
```

Apparently the list implemented by the `tail` pointers contains a reference to the node you `free`d.

An obvious problem here is that you `free` a node `num1` that has `num1->tail == NULL`, but you don't modify the `tail` pointer of its predecessor.

---

**BTW**:
Using a linked list with two pointers per character is an inefficient way to implement something like a dynamically growing character array. A structure like this

```
struct _number {
    size_t memorySize;
    size_t stringLength;
    char *string
}
```

with dynamically allocated memory for `char *string` would be more efficient.
You simply `realloc` the memory if `stringLength`reaches `memorySize`.